# Recover data from USB which doesnt appear to have a partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, usb, partitioning

Possible duplicate but all other example seems to have output for sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdx. Upon inserting the USB the following appears in dmesg· Ubuntu doesn't acknowledge the device in terms of offering to mount etc.

```
adam@horb:~$ dmesg | tail
[ 1808.351548] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 6
[ 1809.726597] usb 2-2: new high-speed USB device number 7 using ehci-pci
[ 1809.864964] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3000
[ 1809.864976] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[ 1809.864985] usb 2-2: Product: SM3252A MEMORY BAR  
[ 1809.864992] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: Silicon Motion,Inc. 
[ 1809.865486] scsi9 : usb-storage 2-2:1.0
[ 1810.861535] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access USB MEMORY BAR   1000 PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[ 1810.863458] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg6 type 0
[ 1810.866537] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdg] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

The device appears in /dev but there are no partitions such as /dev/sdg1 etc as I would expect.

```
adam@horb:~$ ls -larF /dev | grep sdg
brw-rw----   1 root disk        8,  96 Oct 25 18:32 sdg
```

fdisk yields nothing;

```
adam@horb:~$ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdg
adam@horb:~$
```

It is noticed by lsusb

```
adam@horb:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 090c:3000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. USB-2.0 4-Port HUB
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 15d9:0a4d Trust International B.V. Optical Mouse
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 046d:c31c Logitech, Inc. Keyboard K120 for Business
```

Is there any way to recover the data on this USB?

Comment: Have you tried using TestDisk? http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk  I've used it in the past to recover partitions on USB drives.

Comment: A partition isn't necessarily needed, the filesystem can be on `/dev/sdg`. So, try to mount it read-only via `mount -o ro /dev/sdg /some/mountpoint`. `file -s /dev/sdg` might give you a hint, too.

Comment: @JoshR, TestDisk doesn't give /dev/sdg as an option. It only lists my sata drives.

Comment: @mpy, I will attempt your suggestions this evening.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just mount `/dev/sdg` directly (instead of `/dev/sdg1` or so). This will work if the full device (not a partition) was formatted. A tool like `fdisk(8)` (there are several partition managers around) can give you an idea of the partition of the disk.

If the system doesn't recognize the USB stick, it might be that its data was thrashed, or it might be broken.

Comment: I attempted this. I expect the usb was trash, thank you though.